# code asistant comment style

Tags: aptana3

I try to make use of code assistant in Aptana. 
It seems that it is not working with js self written code, or I'm using it the wrong way.

I'm working with Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.2.201208201020

I comment my javascript like so:

```
/**
    Simple utilities like alert/info/error windows etc.
    @constructor
    @param object params - set of key:value properties
 */
function SomeClass(params) 
{   
    /**
    * @var some description
    */
    this.messages = [];

    /**
     * My function
     * 
     * @param string some_param - some description
     */
    this.somefunction = function(some_param)
    {
    //some code
    }
}
```

Now when I type **this.** in **SomeClass** block a popup shows and i can find **messages** and **somefunction** but it say that both have no description.

When I'm in **this.somefunction** section I get proposals for global variables like **window.location** but no help for **this.** nor for **SomeClass**

I'm using this comment style in php and it works like a charm.
What am I doing wrong? This JS comment style was working in my previous eclipse - helios.